# Check whether a widget is in the layout Qt

Tags: qt

How to check whether a widget is in a layout? I have a layout that may contain the widget or not.

- Widget name: `infoClient`
- Layer name:  `verticalLayout_3`

Need to check if the widget exists in the layout, then do not add a new one.
And if does not exist, add a new one.
How to do it?

```
void MainWindow::slotPush1()
{
    if <there is no infoClient> ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(new infoClient(this));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QObject::findChild](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild) to find a child by its name. For instance:

```
void MainWindow::slotPush1()
{
    if (ui->verticalLayout_3->findChild<QWidget*>("infoClient")) // your code to add it here
}
```

Note: findChild is a template function. If you're not familiar with template functions, just know that you pass the type of object you want to find (in your example, it looks like you could use `ui->verticalLayout_3->findChild<infoClient*>("infoClient")`). If you want to find a QWidget, or anything that inherits from QWidget, you can just use `findChild<QWidget*>()` and you'll be safe.

Comment: As noted in other answers, widget is not child of the layout, but child of the parent widget, whether it is in a layout or not.

Comment: Thanks for idea! But your way is not working. Child must seek in the parent widget. I'm doing as: `if (!(ui->centralWidget->findChild<QWidget*>("infoClient"))) ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(new infoClient(this));`

Comment: @SerJS "it works!!" doesn't mean it is correct. You are going to run into trouble as soon as you nest layouts or do anything more than trivial with your widgets.

Comment: I realized that it wasn't good. But this is the easiest way to solve my problem. If troubles will appear I'll use other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Few points:

- The parent of a widget in a layout  is the widget containing the **top-level** layout
- Layouts can be nested.
- A layout contains items ([QLayoutItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html)), which are either layouts (`layout()` is not null) or widgets (`widget()` is not null). In the end you have a tree of layout items.

So You need to do a search from the parent widget (dfs, bfs).

```
bool checkWidgetInsideLayout(const QWidget* _someWidget){

return _someWidget != NULL && 
       _someWidget->parent() != NULL && 
       _someWidget->parent()->layout() != NULL && 
       foundItem(_someWidget->parent()->layout(), _someWidget ); 
}

//clumsy dfs
bool foundItem(const QLayout* layout, const QWidget* _someWidget ){

     for(int i = 0; i < layout->count(); i++){
        QLayoutItem* item = layout->itemAt(i);
        if(item->widget() == _someWidget )
            return true;
         if(item->layout() && foundItem(item->layout(), _someWidget)  )
             return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism within Qt that will perform the check that you are looking for.  You will have to implement it yourself:

```
void MainWindow::slotPush1()
{
   if (doesLayoutContainInfoClient(ui->verticalLayout_3))
   {
      ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(new infoClient(this));
   }
}

bool MainWindow::doesLayoutContainInfoClient(QLayout* layout)
{
   const QString infoClientName("infoClient");

   for (int i=0; i<layout->count(); i++)
   {
      QWidget* layoutWidget = layout->itemAt(i)->widget();
      if (layoutWidget)
      {
         if (infoClientName == layoutWidget->metaObject()->className())
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Despite what I've suggested above, I don't really recommend it.  It makes more sense to store whether or not you've added infoClient to your layout as an independent boolean within your program somewhere.  Querying the contents of layouts in this manner is somewhat unusual, and is messier than just using a `bool`.

Comment: it is a bit more subtle than that. Your solution works for its localized case... not the `Check whether a widget is in the layout Qt`one...

Comment: @UmNyobe True, but the question only seems to be asking for the localized case.  What also seems to be getting missed in a lot of the other answers is that "infoClient" is not, in fact, the widget NAME; it is the widget TYPE (despite what is stated in the question).

Comment: yes you use `infoClient` as class name because what he want is "a singleton behavior" inside the layout i get that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tom Panning's solution to find your child with the `QObject::findChild()` method.
But adding a Widget to QLayout will reparent it to the layout's parent. So you'll have to find it by calling it with the `MainWindow` object like that:

```
void MainWindow::slotPush1()
{
    if (this->findChild<QWidget*>("infoClient")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If your infoClient widget was added in the QtDesigner, you won't have problems with this solution. The designer sets per default the object name.
If the infoClient was added to the layout in your code, you have to set the object name explicitly, otherwise you won't be able to find it because its name is empty:
(Assuming, m_client is a member variable of MainWindow)

```
void MainWindow::createWidgets()
{
    if (infoClientShouldBeAdded) {
        m_client = new infoClient(this);
        m_client->setObjectName("infoClient");
        ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(m_infoClient);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to keep track of the pointers of your created widgets (e.g., by storing them in a std::vector or Qt equivalent). This allows to use  [indexof(QWidget*)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#indexOf):

> Searches for widget widget in this layout (not including child layouts).
>   Returns the index of widget, or -1 if widget is not found.